# How can you export cookies from the Tor Browser Bundle?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, cookies

Cookies don't show up in Privacy & Security Preferences when you click Manage Data (it shows no cookies even when there are cookies), which appears to be inherited from Firefox's Private Browsing mode.

---

As a temporary fix I tried using the extension [cookies.txt](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cookies-txt/), but that didn't work for me, clicking it does nothing.

I tried running its source code directly ([GitHub](https://github.com/lennonhill/cookies-txt)) in Web Developer > Scratchpad, but this didn't work either.

```
function saveCookies(cookies) {
  var header = [
    '# Netscape HTTP Cookie File\n',
    '# https://curl.haxx.se/rfc/cookie_spec.html\n',
    '# This is a generated file! Do not edit.\n\n'
  ];
  var body = cookies.map(formatCookie)
  var blob = new Blob(header.concat(body), {type: 'text/plain'});
  var objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  browser.downloads.download({url: objectURL, filename: 'cookies.txt',
    saveAs: true, conflictAction: 'overwrite'});
}

function handleClick() {
  var gettingAll = browser.cookies.getAll({});
  gettingAll.then(saveCookies);
}

handleClick()
```

It gave this exception, but this could be my fault since I don't know what I'm doing.

```
/*
Exception: ReferenceError: browser is not defined
handleClick@Scratchpad/1:24:7
@Scratchpad/1:28:1
*/
```

---

I also tried looking inside the file `Browser/TorBrowser/Data/Browser/profile.default/cookies.sqlite` while the broswer was open, but the `moz_cookies` column appeared to be empty.

---

Is there some way to export the cookies from the Tor Browser Bundle or even view them at all?

Answer (score 0):

You can control cookie preferences from about:config.

Maybe this link will help:
[About Config Preferences](https://gist.github.com/0XDE57/fbd302cef7693e62c769)

Answer (score 0):

This is not the best solution since it requires you to install an add-on, but it works at least. The [Cookies Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/a-cookie-manager) does let you see and import/export your cookies.

Comment: As I tested, Cookie Managers works in FireFox private mode, but not in TOR browser. I've checked with both yahoo.com and facebookcorewwwi.onion.